# Tkinter dialog's elements position

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, tkinter-entry, toplevel

I am building custom Tkinter dialog window with Entry and Combobox. I am stuck with placing text and enter frames. Currently I am placing them manually. I am looking for the way to let tkinter do it automatically (maybe with pack() method). And also configure TopLevel size automatically.

My code:

```
def ask_unit_len():
    values = ['millimeters', 'micrometers', 'nanometers']
    top = Toplevel()
    top.geometry('170x100')
    top.resizable(False, False)
    top.focus_set()
    top.grab_set()
    top.title('Enter length and units')

    label_length = Label(top, text='Length:')
    label_length.place(x=0, y=0)

    units_type = StringVar()
    length = StringVar()

    answer_entry = Entry(top, textvariable=length, width=10)
    answer_entry.place(x=55, y=0)

    label_units = Label(top, text='Units:')
    label_units.place(x=0, y=30)

    combo = Combobox(top, width=10, textvariable=units_type,
                     values=values)
    combo.place(x=50, y=30)

    button = Button(top, text='Enter',
                    command=lambda:
                    mb.showwarning("Warning",
                                   "Enter all parameters correctly")
                    if (units_type.get() == "" or not length.get().isdigit()
                            or int(length.get()) <= 0)
                    else top.destroy())
    button.place(x=65, y=70)
    top.wait_window(top)
    return int(length.get()), units_type.get()
```

So, is there any way to perform this?

Comment: As you said try using `pack()` or `grid()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I've tried, but it resulted in complete mess.